# Reading integers into different Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am doing some basic coding exercises and there is a problem stuck me.
I need to read a random number of integers from standard input and store them in one vector.
Then reading a second random number of integers and store them in the other one.

Here is my code:

```
vector<int> i_vect1, i_vect2;
int itemp;

cout<<"Input numbers into vector1："<<endl;
while(cin>>itemp){
    i_vect1.push_back(itemp);
}

cout<<"Input numbers into vector2："<<endl;
while(cin>>itemp){
    i_vect2.push_back(itemp);
}
```

When I ran the code, I entered numbers like `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` and press `ctrl+z` to end my input for `vector1`. But it could not read integers to `vector2`, the program ended.

What should I do? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you press ctrl-z, you put `cin` into an error state (eof and fail). As long as it is in this state, all input operations will fail. You need to clear the error state.

```
cin.clear();
```

Then you should be able to read from it again.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, it works! I am new CPPer, a lot of things need to learn:)